# How can I get the entire download path of report in report server, so that i can manually download .RDL file

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am fetching and displaying all the reports in Report server in a grid

[image]

Alongwith View Reports, I also want a Download Report functionality for each report.
How can I download .Rdl file using the download link.
I can give the Download links and download the file using JavaScript.

But, I am not able to get the download path of each report.
Is there a way to get the entire download path of report from Report Server.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to download report definitions (RDL) or export report into something like PDF/DOC etc. ?

Comment: I need to download it, so that admin person can download it and make changes in .RDL file if needed